# OpenCV installation error: No such file or directory "pyopencv_generated_include.h"

Tags: python, c++, linux, opencv

While trying to install `OpenCV` in `linux 18.0.4`, after `sudo make install` command the following error stopped the execution.

```
[ 83%] Linking CXX executable ../../bin/opencv_perf_stitching
[ 83%] Built target opencv_perf_stitching
[ 83%] Generate files for Python bindings and documentation
[ 83%] Built target gen_opencv_python_source
Scanning dependencies of target opencv_python3
[ 83%] Building CXX object modules/python3/CMakeFiles/opencv_python3.dir/__/src2/cv2.cpp.o
/home/kk/opencv-3.4.1/modules/python/src2/cv2.cpp:22:10: fatal error: pyopencv_generated_include.h: No such file or directory
 #include "pyopencv_generated_include.h"
      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
modules/python3/CMakeFiles/opencv_python3.dir/build.make:62: recipe for target 'modules/python3/CMakeFiles/opencv_python3.dir/__/src2/cv2.cpp.o' failed
make[2]: *** [modules/python3/CMakeFiles/opencv_python3.dir/__/src2/cv2.cpp.o] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:28439: recipe for target 'modules/python3/CMakeFiles/opencv_python3.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [modules/python3/CMakeFiles/opencv_python3.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:162: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Any idea what heppend?

I have CUDA 9.2, Python 3.6.5. Follwed the installation instructions given here.: https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2018/05/28/ubuntu-18-04-how-to-install-opencv/

Comment: Can u try installing OpenCV 3.4.3 instead?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue during my OpenCV installation.

We need to execute gen script manually (from /build one level up, in my case, from /opencv-3.4.3, for you, based on your opencv version is /opencv-3.4.1).

So, if you are in /build:

```
cd ..
python ./modules/python/src2/gen2.py ./build/modules/python_bindings_generator ./build/modules/python_bindings_generator/headers.txt
cd build
sudo make install
```

**Sources:**

- https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/10771#issuecomment-376861139
- https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/10771#issuecomment-379949822

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the late reply, but for anyone else who runs into this issue, try checking the directory name you cloned OpenCV into.

I had it under some weird name, changed it to "opencv" then updated the cmakelists.txt and it built fine